# Using cmp with process substitution (stdout)? (Bash)

Tags: c, bash, command-line-interface, mips

For our class, we had to make a C program that encodes MIPS instructions into instruction words and also decodes instruction words into MIPS instructions.

I wrote everything already and tested on some cases, but I wanted to test it on a bigger dataset.

We are given the test files: `test.asm` and `test.bin`.
The `.asm` file has MIPS instructions and the `.bin` file has the equivalent instruction words for those MIPS instructions.

My `decode` function takes in the instruction words from `test.bin`, converts them to equivalent MIPS instructions and sends it to `stdout`.

I want to compare the output from my decode function with the MIPS instructions in the `test.asm` file to see that they are equivalent (that I decoded correctly).

I was told that I could use the `cmp` command with process substitution to compare the two but I don't know what I would put inside the `<(...)`.

I run my program using: `bin/mips -d < test.bin` where the `-d` flag represents `decoding`.

I was thinking maybe it would be like this, but I'm not sure:

`cmp <(cat test.asm) <(bin/mips -d < test.bin)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That command should work, but there's no need to use process substitution with `cat`, just put the filename there:

```
cmp test.asm <(bin/mips -d < test.bin)
```

Comment: This worked for me! However, I am curious what the difference is between your answer and the one below by @morgano? I tried both and both gave me the same line number and byte number where the two outputs differed.

Comment: His takes advantage of the fact that `cmp` will read from standard input if either of the filenames is missing or `-`. Mine uses a shell feature to emulate a file with using process substitution. Just different ways to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about using the format `cmp file1 file2`, but you can do `file1 | cmp file2` like this:

`bin/mips -d test.bin | cmp test.asm`